# Why did the Fourth Crusade sack Constantinople?

Tags: byzantine-empire, crusades

If the Crusade was going to help the Byzantines to drive away their enemies, as well as attack the Holy land, why did it turn on the Byzantine Empire?

Comment: aea, can you tell us the situation that led to such a question? Why do you need such a explanation? How did you try to look for such a thing?

Comment: Sometimes, I like to listen to what other people have to say. the situation is that if the 4th crusade hadn't attacked the Empire, I might be living in Greece. That is why. Also, the crusaders carried off priceless religious objects, which makes me very mad.

Comment: aea, ah, I see, then, if so, the question should be closed due to the lack of well founded presuppositions or basises.

Comment: This is a "bad" question for the site because it doesn't look like you've done any research. Members of the site prefer to deal with questioners who have PART of the question under their "control" and need help filling some gaps.

Comment: Personally, I disagree with you @Carlo_R. . There needn't be a reason based on actual problems for every question. See http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/a/237/961

Comment: @aea2o5 Per the [FAQ], questions answered by a simple Google search or Wikipedia page are off-topic. Does the [Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_crusade#Diversion_to_Constantinople) answer your question? If not, please edit your question to be more specific as to what you don't understand and we'll be happy to help you.

Comment: money.  total badass pulled it off http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enrico_Dandolo.  he was blind at the time of the operation

Comment: Jonathan Phillips' *The Fourth Crusade and the Sack of Constantinople* answers this question, and is fairly well written...

Comment: That crusade requested the use of the fleet of the italian city of Venice. Both cities were rival in trade and influence. Venice also requested due payment for the use of its fleet (which no one could afford). Ergo, the sack which was agreed by the crusaders to pay for the fleet. The crusade never reached Jerusalem. Venice became the richest and most powerful city and got control over its competitor